# Using PowerShell ISE, if I open it by clicking on the .ps1 file it works, if use File->Open the same file gets errors

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Using PowerShell ISE,

If I open the file below by clicking on the .ps1 file in windows explorer, when I run it with the green arrow, it works.
If use File->Open the same file, when I click the green arrow I get errors.

If I open it by clicking and then load it, it's fine, so something (the path?) is getting set when I double click that is not the other way...

Let me clarify... If I open the file one way(double click) it 'compiles' fine, if I open it the other way (file->Open) the exact same file does not 'compile'. I'm hoping to figure out why this is. My guess is that the path variable it uses to find the other files needed is set different via the two methods of opening (because many of the errors are 'not found')

here is the code of the file (it basically just calls a bunch of external stuff)

```
###########################################################
# RUN (hit the green arrow) TO INITIALIZE
############################################################

############################################################
# set defaults
$path = Get-Location    
$ProjectName = $path.Path 
$ProjectName = $ProjectName.Replace("D:\Project Files\", "")
$ProjectName = $ProjectName.Replace("\_Powershell", "")
$ProjectName = $ProjectName.Replace("\WebApp", "")
$ProjectName = $ProjectName.Replace("\Webapp", "")
write-host "Project Name found: "  $ProjectName 
$Project = $ProjectName 
$RootPath = 'D:\Project Files\' + $Project + '\WebApp'
$ModulePath = 'D:\Project Files\' + $Project + '\WebApp\_PowerShell'

############################################################
# call this one to remove and reload the modules (if modules are modified)
function ReloadTemplates {

    RemoveLoadedModule WPK
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcAddFileToProjectGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcEoAndMap
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcEoAndMapGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcDal
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcDalGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcBll
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcBLLGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcView
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcViewGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcController
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcControllerGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcAutoMap
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcAutoMapGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcReport
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcReportGui
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcCv
    RemoveLoadedModule JcdcCvGui
    RemoveLoadedModule ReadWriteXML

    # load the Templates
    LoadTemplates
}
function RemoveLoadedModule { 
    param($PathAndName) 

    if(Get-Module -name $PathAndName)
    { 
        Remove-Module $PathAndName
    } 
} 

############################################################
# call this one to load the modules
function LoadTemplates {

    Import-Module WPK
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcAddFileToProjectGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcEoAndMap.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcEoAndMapGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcDal.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcDalGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcBll.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcBLLGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcView.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcViewGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcController.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcControllerGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcAutoMap.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcAutoMapGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcReport.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcReportGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcCv.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcCvGui.psm1"
    Import-Module "$ModulePath\ReadWriteXML.psm1"

    Initialize-AddFileToProject $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-EOMAPGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-DALGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-BLLGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-ViewGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-ControllerGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-AutoMapGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-ReportGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-CVGui $RootPath $Project
    Initialize-XMLArguments
}

############################################################
# load the Templates on Run (when green arrow is clicked)
ReloadTemplates

############################################################
# Type one of the following in the command window

#Select-A  + <tab>  =  Select-AddFileToProject       -To create file to add to project
#Select-B  + <tab>  =  Select-BLLWhatToBuild         -To add a BLL
#Select-C  + <tab>  =  Select-ControllerWhatToBuild  -To add a Controller
#Select-D  + <tab>  =  Select-DALWhatToBuild         -To add a DAL
#Select-E  + <tab>  =  Select-EoAndMapBuild          -To add a Eo and Map 
#Select-M  + <tab>  =  Select-MapBuild               -To add a AutoMap
#Select-R  + <tab>  =  Select-ReportWhatToBuild      -To add a Report
#Select-Vi + <tab>  =  Select-ViewWhatToBuild        -To add a View
#Select-Vm + <tab>  =  Select-VmCvOrExcel            -To add a CV, VM, D:\PowerShellTemplatesArgsor Excel
```

Here are the errors

```
PS U:\> D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1
Project Name found:  U:\
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcAddFileToProjectGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module direc
tory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:61 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcAddFileToProjectGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...ProjectGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcEoAndMap.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:62 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcEoAndMap.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...dcEoAndMap.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcEoAndMapGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:63 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcEoAndMapGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...oAndMapGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcDal.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:64 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcDal.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...ll\JcdcDal.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcDalGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:65 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcDalGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...JcdcDalGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcBll.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:66 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcBll.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...ll\JcdcBll.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcBLLGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:67 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcBLLGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...JcdcBLLGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcView.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:68 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcView.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...l\JcdcView.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcViewGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:69 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcViewGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...cdcViewGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcController.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:70 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcController.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...Controller.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcControllerGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:71 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcControllerGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...trollerGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcAutoMap.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:72 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcAutoMap.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...cdcAutoMap.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcAutoMapGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:73 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcAutoMapGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...AutoMapGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcReport.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:74 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcReport.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...JcdcReport.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcReportGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:75 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcReportGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...cReportGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcCv.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:76 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcCv.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...ell\JcdcCv.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\JcdcCvGui.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:77 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\JcdcCvGui.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...\JcdcCvGui.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\Project Files\U:\\WebApp\_PowerShell\ReadWriteXML.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:78 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  "$ModulePath\ReadWriteXML.psm1"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (D:\Project File...adWriteXML.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
The term 'Initialize-AddFileToProject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was includ
ed, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:80 char:29
+     Initialize-AddFileToProject <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-AddFileToProject:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-EOMAPGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, veri
fy that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:81 char:24
+     Initialize-EOMAPGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-EOMAPGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-DALGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
 that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:82 char:22
+     Initialize-DALGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-DALGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-BLLGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
 that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:83 char:22
+     Initialize-BLLGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-BLLGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-ViewGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verif
y that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:84 char:23
+     Initialize-ViewGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-ViewGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-ControllerGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
 verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:85 char:29
+     Initialize-ControllerGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-ControllerGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-AutoMapGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, ve
rify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:86 char:26
+     Initialize-AutoMapGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-AutoMapGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-ReportGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, ver
ify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:87 char:25
+     Initialize-ReportGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-ReportGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-CVGui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:88 char:21
+     Initialize-CVGui <<<<  $RootPath $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-CVGui:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The term 'Initialize-XMLArguments' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Powershell\ManualRun.ps1:89 char:28
+     Initialize-XMLArguments <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize-XMLArguments:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is there some way to set the path when I do a file open so this does not occur?

There are different versions of this folder and file for each project, as it's used to generate project specific code...
so the solution needs to work for that scenerio too please.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your question, but if you want to really begin at the location of your script, you can use `$MyInvocation` automatic var.

`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` will give you the path of your script (.PS1 file) and then you can use `Split-Path` to find its directory location. I think that in your case `Get-Location` does not always return the path you think about.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify... If I open the file one way(double click) it 'compiles' fine, if I open it the other way (file->Open) the exact same file does not 'compile'. I'm hoping to figure out why this is. My guess is that the path variable it uses to find the other files needed is set different via the two methods of opening (because many of the errors are 'not found')

Comment: First PowerShell is interpreted, Second do you log the result of Get-Location in each of your cases ? are they the same ?

Comment: Try this, when you get the error, in the console prompt in ISE, type pwd and see what you get. the path may be getting set by a user profile that moves the path to a set location.

Comment: He's saying that when you open the script by executing the file `Get-Location` = `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`.  When you open PowerShell first, your default path is U:, and `Get-Location` returns that path.  I.e. **Powershell changes to the directory of the script you open when you doubleclick that script.  It does not do the same thing when you open the script within ISE.**

Answer (score 1):

```
$ModulePath = 'D:\Project Files\' + $Project + '\WebApp\_PowerShell'
Import-Module "$ModulePath\JcdcAddFileToProjectGui.psm1"
```

Results in

```
'D:\Project Files\U:\WebApp_PowerShell\JcdcAddFileToProjectGui.psm1'
```

Windows does not allow more than one drive letter in a single path.  Yours has U: in it.  $Project = 'U:' at the time `$ModulePath` was evaluated.  That is your starting working directory for PowerShell.

Bottom line is that you're using paths relative to where the script is run.  When you open powershell, it sets starting location from your profile, or default location if you don't have one in your profile.  When you launch from a file, it uses that file's location.

You seem to be hard coding a separate set of script + modules, etc., for each project, but they have defined names that are consistent across the range of projects.  **I suggest you hardcode the module locations in each script.**

I'd also suggest that you reconsider this style of coding.  It must be a nightmare to change something.  What if you created a single script that loads a single module.  Then create a config file for each project and a shortcut to your script that loads the main script with the customized parts read from the config file.

Answer (score 1):

The modules lay in same directory like a script? If it true, then reason of issue is in curent directoty. Add folowing line in begin or before you operate with modules:

```
Set-Location "<...>"
```

and lets type path to the folder with your script instead <...>.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like using the default Var $PSScriptRoot

In your case I would have started the script
`Set-Location $PSScripRoot`

## this will set the location to where ever your script is this should make it so either a double click or an open file location and press play will excute your script

you can either add my line in front of `$path = Get-Location` or you can eliminate the $path line entirely and just use the $PSScriptRoot line but then you also need to replace the $path variable with $PSScriptRoot in your entire script

As others have said when you double click your script Powershell uses that path if you open manually via ISE it does not (it uses whatever the last path u set in ISE instead)
what the line Set-Location $PSScriptRoot does is take the local path of your script always regardless how you choose to start it

I hope this helps!